# Where to find non-anecdotal and up-to-date information regarding the cost of living in other countries?

Tags: cost-of-living

In the near future I'd like to emigrate from the UK. A lot of people have given me well-intentioned, but anecdotal information regarding living cost abroad. Where do people find legit and up-to-date information?

Comment: Can we split this into two questions? Perhaps keep this one as living costs of other countries - they're quite separate topics (that and jobs) and would be more answerable as two questions.

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for? "Living cost" depends on so many factors that I find it a pretty ill-defined concept.

Answer (score 4):

I've moved around a lot, between countries and cities.

One of the most convenient 'real' sources is [Expatistan](https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living).

It allows you to compare COL between two cities, which is much more useful than UN indices of countries.

It takes real prices from people and summarises them in food, housing, clothes, transportation, personal care and entertainment.

I've used it myself for comparisons and it's my go to site for not only moving, but also to get an indication when travelling on holiday to city x, to get an idea of how expensive the trip is going to be.